# Animation Nodes Replicate Object Dynamic Paint

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

Is there a way to drive the transformations of an array of objects with a dynamic paint map or texture? This would permit more complex patterns to be achieved.

I've seen a dozen tutorials that all show the same techniques, but nothing yet that can be used to make a custom shape or pattern.  With this I hope to control the rotation, position, scale, and color of these arrays.

[image: Animation Nodes to Project Images or Shapes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can output the dynamic paint data to a vertex group and use its weight in your node tree. In the following example, we add a vertex group `dp_weight` and use its weight to control the amount of translation in each instance:

[image: Node Tree]